# Obtain data from internet

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to fetch the data from the following page: [Page](https://lectortmo.com/) What I'm trying to do is that if the user typed something in the EditText and pressed the button, a RecyclerView with an Array of everything that search brings up is loaded. The downside is that I can't parse the page data well. When searching, for example, the words just leveling the url becomes this: [Page](https://lectortmo.com/library?_page=1&title=solo+leveling). And as you can see, I can't bring up the title or the image:

[image]

This is the code for the page's `body` when searching (I simplified it):

```
<body>
    <div id="app" class="pb-5">
     <main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="element  col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 mt-2 " data-identifier="41512">
    <a href=" https://lectortmo.com/library/manhwa/41512/solo-leveling"> <div class="thumbnail book book-thumbnail-41512">
    <style>
                    .book-thumbnail-41512::before{
                        background-image: url('https://otakuteca.com/images/books/cover/5c2efcd42cd5e.jpg');
                    }
                </style>
    <div class="thumbnail-title">
    <h4 class="text-truncate" title="Solo Leveling">Solo Leveling</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a> </div> <div class="element  col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 mt-2 " data-identifier="48448">
    <a href=" https://lectortmo.com/library/manhwa/48448/love-leveling"> <div class="thumbnail book book-thumbnail-48448">
    <style>
                    .book-thumbnail-48448::before{
                        background-image: url('https://otakuteca.com/images/books/cover/5ed182d1c909d.jpg');
                    }
                </style>
    <div class="thumbnail-title">
    <h4 class="text-truncate" title="Love Leveling ">Love Leveling </h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a> </div> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </main>
    </div>
    </body>
```

And this is how I am parsing the **data**:

```
@Override
            protected ArrayList<ParseItem> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                String texto = textoBusqueda.getText().toString();
                String arreglo = texto.replace(' ', '+');
                String url = "https://lectortmo.com/library?_page=1&title=" + arreglo;
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    
                    Elements data = doc.select("div.row");
                    int size = data.size();
                    Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
                    Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
                    Log.d("size", ""+size);
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        String title = data.select("div.thumbnail-title")
                                .select("h4")
                                .eq(i)
                                .attr("tittle"); //nombre del manhwa
                        String imgUrl = data.select("style")
                                .select("background-image")
                                .eq(i)
                                .attr("url"); //imagen del manga
                        String detailUrl = data.select("div.row")
                                .select("a")
                                .eq(i)
                                .attr("href");
                        String urlManga = data.select("div.row")
                                .select("a")
                                .eq(i)
                                .attr("href");
    
                        parseItems.add(new ParseItem(imgUrl, title, detailUrl, urlManga));
                    }
                }  catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return parseItems;
            }
```

Could someone tell me how I can do it correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your first `select` returns 7 elements but there should be only two so let's start with tweaking the selector, use:
  `Elements data = doc.select("div.row>.element");`
  Now `size` is `2`.
- The other thing is you don't have to use: `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` but let's use `for (Element e : data)` so you don't have to use `.eq(i)` anymore, just use `e`.
- You have a typo, it should be `"title"` instead of `"tittle"`.
- Now you can get detail URL with simpler selector: `String detailUrl = e.select("a").attr("href");`
- I don't understand what you want to get as `urlManga` as each of them has only one link.
- Getting `imgUrl` is difficult as the url is in `<style>` and Jsoup can't parse what's inside so you'll have to use regular expressions to get the URL or just do some creative string splitting.

After all suggestions your code should look like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Elements data = doc.select("div.row>.element");
int size = data.size();
Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
Log.d("size", ""+size);
for (Element e : data) {
    String title = e.select("h4").attr("title"); // nombre del manhwa
    String imgUrl = e.select("style").first().html().split("url\\('")[1].split("'\\)")[0]; // imagen del manga
    String detailUrl = e.select("a").attr("href").trim();
    String urlManga = "???";

    parseItems.add(new ParseItem(imgUrl, title, detailUrl, urlManga));
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for answer me. Now, i've a dude, how to work this: `>` in `div.row>`? and in the case that i trying obtain data from a `li` how i can do it? example: `<div class="one"><div class="two"><div class="three"><ul class="example"><li class="list-chapters"><a class="example"> Chapter One </a">` I need obtain this: **Chapter One** and show in a `TextView`

Comment: `div.row>.element` means: find `div`s with class `row` and then find their direct children with class `element`. A space would also work here instead of `>` but I used it to emphasize we're looking for direct child elements. To get the `li` in your example use you can use selector `ul.example li` (or `ul.example>li`). You can read more about [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) but don't be scared as in 99% cases only few of them are enough to get all you want. You can also [play a game](https://flukeout.github.io/).